# Cassandra frozen keyword meaning

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, keyword

What's the meaning of the `frozen` keyword in Cassandra?

I'm trying to read this documentation page: [Using a user-defined type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html), but their explanation for the `frozen` keyword (which they use in their examples) is not clear enough for me:

> To support future capabilities, a column definition of a user-defined
>   or tuple type requires the frozen keyword. Cassandra serializes a
>   frozen value having multiple components into a single value. For
>   examples and usage information, see "Using a user-defined type",
>   "Tuple type", and Collection type.

I haven't found any other definition or a clear explanation for that in the net.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**In Cassandra if you define UDT or Collection as frozen, you can't update UDT's or collection's individual item, you have to reinsert with full value.**

> A frozen value serializes multiple components into a single value. Non-frozen types allow updates to individual fields. Cassandra treats the value of a frozen type as a blob. The entire value must be overwritten.

Source : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html

@Alon : **"Long story short: frozen = immutable"**

Comment: Long story short: frozen = immutable

Comment: Is there a difference between `frozen<set<udt>>` and `set<frozen<udt>>`?

Comment: @jaco0646 for both of the types you can insert in a same way but you can't add (append) new udt in the `frozen<set<udt>>`

Comment: @jaco0646 I think both are the same, however, we create the column its displays the same while describing the table. Also both behave the same manner.

Answer (score 2):

For a user-defined type, I have noticed that you can update frozen the set by adding or removing the set elements. For example, let's say we create a table as follows.

```
create type rule_option_udt(display text, code text);
create TABLE rules (key text, options set<frozen<rule_option_udt>>, primary key (key));
```

As per the definition we expect that we won't be able to use + or - operation with the options field. But you can use add or remove operation as a normal set.

```
insert into rules (key, options) values ('fruits', {{display: 'Apple', code: 'apple'}})  ;

update rules set options = options + {{display: 'Orange', code: 'orange'}};
```

The above update is valid but you can't do the same with simple types such as text. I am not sure if this is expected nature or not but this is how it works for me.

In addition to this `<frozen<set<udt>>` && `set<frozen<udt>>` are behaving in the same manner. While describing the table you can see both are being shown as `set<frozen<udt>>`