# Setting default unset value for user defined data type fields in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am storing nested JSON values in Cassandra,Since I have lot fields, is there way to keep unset values for the fields not coming in

Consider I have a Table like below,

```
CREATE TYPE address (number int, street text, address2 text);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
            street_address frozen<address>
);

INSERT INTO users JSON '{"id": 5, "street_address": 
   {"number": 123, "street": "Main St."}}';
```

If I ran the above query below is the column value,

```
5   {number:123,street:'Main St.',address2:NULL}
```

I want to ignore this `address2:NULL` insertion in 2nd column. I tried "default unset" also but it is not working

I just framed with the 2 fields in this table, similiar to I have multiple fields with nested JSON objects. Is there any workaround to avoid null insertion

Answer (score 1):

Answer after updated question (**Update on 15.10.2019: updated answer is incorrect because of the copy-paste error in this example (users vs users2)!** - it looks like that when updating from JSON, the UDT is replaced completely):

You're using the `frozen` UDT here, and it's updated at once ([as one binary object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532743/cassandra-frozen-keyword-meaning)), so if the field is missing in data then it's represented as `null`.  But if you're using non-frozen UDT, then `DEFAULT UNSET` works as required - the missing field doesn't overwrite existing value:

```
cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO users2 JSON '{"id": 5, "street_address": {"number": 123, 
    "street": "Main St.", "address2": "test" }}';
cqlsh:test> SELECT * from users2;

 id | street_address
----+-----------------------------------------------------
  5 | {number: 123, street: 'Main St.', address2: 'test'}

(1 rows)
cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO users JSON '{"id": 5, "street_address": {"number": 1234, 
    "street": "Main St.3"}}' DEFAULT UNSET ;
cqlsh:test> SELECT * from users2;

 id | street_address
----+-----------------------------------------------------
  5 | {number: 123, street: 'Main St.', address2: 'test'}

(1 rows)
```

First variant of the answer:

By default, JSON is inserted with `DEFAULT NULL` option specified - this means that all missing fields are replaced with `null`, so they can delete existing data.  If you want to have them unset, then you need to specify corresponding option after the JSON value, like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable JSON '{ "\"myKey\"": 0, "value": 0}' DEFAULT UNSET;
```

See [Cassandra documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cql/json.html#insert-json) for clarification on this topic.

P.S. If I remember correctly, this option may not exist in every Cassandra version.

Comment: Thanks for your time spending on this, and this will be absolutely  fine for primitive data type, but I am trying to insert user defined type(frozen) using spring, and in my case there are 260 fields in JSON object. So out of that 260 fields I want to restrict null values insertion which are all not coming in the input

Comment: *But if you're using non-frozen UDT, then DEFAULT UNSET works as required - the missing field doesn't overwrite existing value*, could you please point to some docs that explain how to achieve that, maybe with some examples, because I ran your code sample from the answer (changing `insert into users2` to `insert into users`, which I assume was a typo) and the value IS being overwritten with `null`, please help

Comment: @Scaramouche - you're right - that was a copy paste error in my test - I selected from incorrect table. But it looks like it's a limitation of JSON input + UDTs